# How can you get the date modified for a windows 8 file?

Tags: properties, windows-8

getting data created for a file is easy

```
StorageFile myFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile");
var dateCreated = myFile.DateCreated;
```

but there is no corresponding myFile.DateModified.

is there anyway to get the data modified property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get BasicProperties, this may have been removed in RP.
My solution was the convoluted

```
var check = new list<string>(); 
check.Add("System.DateModified"); 
var props = await myFile.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(check); 
var dateModified = props.SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

phew, that was hard work

Answer (score 2):

According to Ari Polski "You can get date modified through the BasicProperties"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/no/winappswithcsharp/thread/0f3b989a-fb20-4313-b9ea-61aec477dc63

Answer (score 0):

(await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).DateModified does the same thing